# Repl.it listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I have recently modified my files for my discord bot, and then I got this randomly. I've not seen this happening before; logged before.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Mitch'))
app.listen(port, () => 
console.log('Mitch is online.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have an application running. There's a "Stop" button on the top of the page, maybe you can close your server there. If you started it over the command line, see if you have running background tasks with the command "jobs" inside the terminal. It will list you all tasks running in the background. You can bring them to foreground with 'fg' and then kill it with control-c.
If you're on your pc running your application, you can run 'lsof -i tcp:3001' to see which process is running on that port and then kill it with 'kill -9 ', with  being the process id returned from lsof.